# Image isn't showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can you help me with this? Since I'm newbie on using javascript, I've copied the code from a certain site(It's free to copy the code. And I admire the coder.). This assignment will be due tomorrow so I don't have the time to research on this. Can you please help me. Btw, This is my first time to post. Please be gentle on answering. Thank you in advance.

This is the HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>A really simple slideshow</h1>
        <ul class="slider">
        <li><img src="images/garmin1.jpg" height="337" width="600" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/garmin2.jpg" height="337" width="600" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/garmin1.jpg" height="337" width="600" /></li></ul>
        <p>I went to see <a href="http://trailers.apple.com/trailers/wb/gravity/" title="           Watch the Gravity trailer">Gravity</a> today. It was amazeballs.</p>

</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS

```
body {
  font: 1em/125% tahoma, sans-serif;
  background:#111;
  color:#c8c8c8;
}

#container {
  width:600px;
  padding:20px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size:2em;
  padding-bottom:.5em;
  border-bottom:1px solid #cecece;
}

h1, p {
  margin: .8em 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
  font-style:italic;
  color:#cecece;
  transition:all .5s;
}

a:hover {
  color:#eeeeee;
}

.slider {
  position:relative;
  height:337px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.slider li {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

This is the javascript

```
$(function(){
  var $slider = $('.slider');
  var $slide = 'li';
  var $delayTime = 1000;//fade in time
  var $transitionTime = 3000;

  function Slides() {
    return $slider.find($slide);
  }

  Slides().fadeOut();

  Slides().first().addClass('active').fadeIn();

  //Auto scroll
  $interval = setInterval(function(){
    var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();
    Slides().eq($i)
      .removeClass('active')
      .fadeOut($transitionTime);

    if(Slides().length == $i + 1) {
      $i=-1; 
    }

    Slides().eq($i + 1)
      .fadeIn($transitionTime)
      .addClass('active');

  }, $transitionTime + $delayTime);


});
```

Comment: i advice making a jsfiddle, it's free ;): http://jsfiddle.io

Comment: The URLs you used in the `src` of your `img` tags are relative paths. Make sure the images are at the right location (in an `images` directory next to the HTML document you're calling in your browser)

Comment: can you attach a picture of your folders hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested your code with good results. Here is my `testing fiddle`:

[YOUR SLIDESHOW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/25kvvhd5/)

You only have to make sure that:

- the paths to the images are correct
- you are loading jquery

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can see that you performed it the way I want it to be. I am pretty sure that the images are in the right location. One thing that is I'm not sure of.. if I am loading the jquery right? What do I need to consider?

Comment: There are several ways to to this. You can host jquery on your server or load it remote. You can load it to your website in the <head> or footer section. But for the first time all you have to know is here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp

Comment: After loading your page, check in your browser console if the `jQuery` variable is defined. If it isn't then JQuery isn't loaded. Since it seems you gave us your whole HTML file, we can see that you're not even calling JQuery's script, try doing that.

Comment: Does my "sample.js" or my script file differ from the jQuery?

Comment: No, but jquery is a library that is needed by your sample.js file -  its a kind of dependency. Thats why its key to first load jquery and after that your js-file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed to include Jquery library in your HTML.

Just add following line to `<head></head>` of your HTML,

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For better understanding check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp)...

Comment: Thank you. I added that line to the very top of my head section. Now it works like a charm.